# References for vector valued spaces like $\mathcal C^\infty(A,C_0^\infty(B))$

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces

I'm reading a text that use the space $\mathcal C^\infty(A,C_0^\infty(B))$, where $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $B\subset\mathbb R^m$ are opens. I've found, in Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and kernels by F. Treves an isomorphism between $\mathcal C^\infty(A,C^\infty(B))$ and $\mathcal C^\infty(A\times B)$ and an isomorphism between $\mathcal C_0^\infty(A,C_0^\infty(B))$ and $\mathcal C_0^\infty(A\times B)$, but I didn't find about the mixed space $\mathcal C^\infty(A,C_0^\infty(B))$. I was wondering if these spaces can be described as the space of all functions $f \in \mathcal C^\infty(A\times B)$ which has compact suport in the second variable. Where can I find more information about this kind of spaces?